# Why is the UTC time in C++ 8 seconds ahead of the actual UTC time?

Tags: c++, docker

I have a simple function to print the current UTC time every second. Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <time.h>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;

void printTime(){
    time_t now = time(0);
    tm *gmtm = gmtime(&now);
    char* dt = asctime(gmtm);
    cout << dt << endl;
}

int main(void) {
    while(true){
        printTime();
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(1000));
    }

    return(0);
}
```

My code prints a different time than the actual UTC time (compared to both my local machine and a website).

For example ...

My code prints `Sun May 13 00:55:30 2018`.

My local machine prints `Sun May 13 00:55:22 2018` (I print it from a terminal with `date -u`).

Some website prints `Sun May 13 00:55:22 2018` (same as my local machine).

What did I do wrong? Please help :(

[EDIT]
I use Docker.

Comment: My first instinct is leap seconds.

Comment: Can you give details of your system, OS, compiler and timezone? I don't see the same problem on my system

Comment: Also see if the discrepancy occurs in `date; date -u`

Comment: do u remember to flush your output buffers?

Comment: @StephenQuan - the `<< endl` will do that.

Comment: Sorry! I forget to mention that I use Docker. Turns out if I exec to the Docker bash and try `date -u`, It will print ahead 10 seconds from the actual UTC time.

Comment: Thank you guys for the answer, turns out its docker container problem that the time usually out of sync and need some tweak. I will close this issue, thank you again!